# Can generatorizing a list improve Python performance?

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, generator

```
def numbers(mi, ma):
    return [n for n in range(mi, ma + 1)]

def gen(xs):
    return (x for x in xs)

example = gen(numbers(10, 20))
```

In this example, can `gen` improve iteration performance of `numbers`? Why (not)?

```
def numbersGen(mi, ma):
    return gen([n for n in range(mi, ma + 1)]) # Generator from list comprehension?
```

Can Python get as lazy as Haskell?

Comment: Python cannot be 'as lazy as' Haskell because it operates fundamentally differently. In the shown code the list is created *before* it is returned from numbers; it is the returned list that is wrapped with the generator. The same holds for the "direct" form. I would be very doubtful if the generator is somehow 'faster at iteration' than iteration of the list which is has already been realized.

Comment: I understand Python's basic operation order; I'm wondering if there are optimization benefits or syntactic especialnesses.

Comment: There is little Python can do/does to optimize such cases - each expression is eagerly evaluated to a value, as it is 'executed', before it can feed the next. This is similar to most common languages (from JavaScript to C#) and is a drastically different fundamental approach than Haskell which is a pure functional language. Python programs have to add back select laziness, such as using a generator without pre-materialization of the source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this particular case, `range` is already about as lazy as you can hope for. There's no reason to further wrap its output in layers of indirection. Of course, the usual caveats of Python generators vs. Haskell laziness apply; namely, iterating through multiple times, or continuing from a specific point multiple times, is painful in Python, but the memory usage is generally more predictable as a result.

Comment: @mentalCase Good to know! I've updated my answer, thanks.